# Query String parameters returns null in wowza

Tags: wowza

In wowza application, trying to get querystring parameters. But it always returns empty. My url is this one

```
rtmp://localhost:1935/myapp/?79ab25d0-770f-427a-ab2f-27e62eeb9e3b_km
rtmp://localhost:1935/myapp/?u=km
```

In both cases its always return empty. My code is as below

```
String querystring = stream.getClient().getQueryStr();
```

I just copied application.xml of vod and only replaced application name VOD to myapp, rest it is same of application.xml of vod.

And using smil file to play videos but that in that case it throws this error

```
MediaReaderH264.open[myapp/_definst_]: Not found: C:/Program Files (x86)/Wowza Media Systems/Wowza Streaming Engine 4.7.5/content/.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Streaming Engine 4.7.5\content (Access is denied)|at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)|at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Unknown Source)|at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)|at com.wowza.io.WowzaRandomAccessFile.<init>(WowzaRandomAccessFile.java:12)|at com.wowza.io.DirectRandomAccessReader.open(DirectRandomAccessReader.java:236)|
```

However full access is given to content folder and all files in this folder.